# Zweite Bedeutung von »nachweisen« in der Juristensprache

Tags: meaning, legal-terminology

In [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15638/2594) wird folgender Satz aus einem Dokument im Zusammenhang einer Wohnungsvermietung zitiert:

> Der Mietinteressent bestätigt, o.g. ihm unbekannte vermietbare Wohnung vom Makler nachgewiesen sowie komplette Daten erhalten zu haben.

Wenn ich das für diese Frage Irrelevante entferne und einen handlicheren Satzbau nutze, bleibt:

> Der Mietinteressent bestätigt, dass der Makler ihm die Wohnung nachgewiesen hat und er komplette Daten erhalten hat.

Es geht mir nun um das Wort *jmd. etw. nachweisen,* das in seiner normalsprachlichen Bedeutung (jmd. etwas beweisen) hier nicht so richtig passt, da es dann nur um den Beweis der Existenz der Wohnung ginge. Ich vermute aber dass der Sinn dieser Passage in etwa ist, sich abzusichern, dass der Mieter die Wohnung gezeigt bekommen hat (und nicht im Nachhinein behaupten kann, über gewisse Aspekte getäuscht worden zu sein, die zwar nicht schriftlich festgehalten sind, aber bei einer Wohnungsbesichtigung jedem ersichtlich sind wie z. B. die genaue Geometrie der Wohnung).

Der Duden listet auch tatsächlich für *nachweisen* eine zweite Bedeutung:

> jemandem etwas, was man ihm vermittelt, angeben und ihn mit den entsprechenden Informationen darüber versehen
>
> **Gebrauch**
>   Amtssprache
>
> **Beispiel**
>   jemandem eine Arbeitsstelle nachweisen

Ich interpretiere *[angeben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/angeben)* mal im Sinne von *Auskunft über etwas geben* (alles andere passt noch weniger). Damit haben wir in etwa dreimal dasselbe. Zur Verdeutlichung setze ich einfach mal stumpf alle Definitionen in den ursprünglichen Satz ein:

> Der Mietinteressent bestätigt, dass der Makler ihm über die Wohnung Auskunft gegeben und ihn mit Informationen darüber versehen hat und er komplette Daten erhalten hat.

Deswegen lässt mich das irgendwie unbefriedigt zurück und meine Frage lautet: **Hat irgendjemand andere Quellen über die Bedeutung von *nachweisen* im Behördendeutsch oder kann sie anhand von eindeutigen Beispielen erläutern?**

Comment: Der Zweck der zitierten Passage ist nach meinem Verständnis, dem Makler zu bestätigen, daß er im Fall eines Vertragsabschlusses berechtigt ist, die Provision zu kassieren. Also in etwa "ich habe zuerst über den Makler erfahren, daß diese Wohnung existiert und zu vermieten ist". Um vollständige und richtige Angaben oder gar das Zeigen der realen Wohnung geht es dabei nicht.

Comment: Ich sehe hier nicht dreimal dasselbe. "über die Wohnung Auskunft gegeben": Der Makler hat mitgeteilt, *dass* die Wohnung existiert. "mit Informationen darüber versehen": Der Makler hat etwas *über* die Wohnung mitgeteilt. "er komplette Daten erhalten hat": Der Makler hat keine Daten zurückgehalten.

Comment: Der Satzbau ist in der Tat komisch. Ohne Schnickschnack steht da: "Der Mietinteressent bestätigt, die Wohnung vom Makler nachgewiesen zu haben." Da fehlt doch mindestens ein "bekommen". Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass das "erhalten" vorher ein "bekommen" war, das sich sowohl auf das physische Bekommen der Daten als auch auf das passive Nachgewiesenbekommen bezog.

Comment: @Matthias: Das ist in der Tat gut möglich und ich hatte nicht daran gedacht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bereits in Grimms "Deutschem Wörterbuch" findet sich folgende Bedeutung des Verbs ["nachweisen"](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN01901#XGN01901):

> **2a)** *anzeigen wo etwas zu finden, dasz und wo etwas vorhanden ist* ...
>   folgend dem weg des geschicks, den die göttliche mutter mir nachwies. Voss Än. 1, 382;
>   von fünf, sechs einwohnern (Nürnbergs) wuszte mir kaum éiner Dürers leichenstein nachzuweisen. Zelter an Göthe 4, 411;

(Zelter wollte sicher nicht den Beweis erbracht sehen, daß Dürer in Nürnberg begraben ist. Er wollte einfach nur gezeigt/gesagt bekommen, wo genau denn nun das Grab sei.)

Diese Bedeutung von "nachweisen" hat offenbar (d.h. ich habe abgesehen vom Duden keine explizite Aussage dazu gefunden, nur die folgenden Beispiele) im Sprachgebrauch der Gesetze und Verordnungen in Bezug auf das Zusammenbringen von Anbietern und Nachfragern¹ überlebt: das Aufzeigen (Angeben, Anzeigen), daß und wo etwas vorhanden ist, wird als "nachweisen" bezeichnet:

> **[Gesetz über das Kreditwesen §1](http://www.gesetzesweb.de/KWG.html)**
>   1a) ... Finanzdienstleistungen sind
>   1. die Vermittlung von Geschäften über die Anschaffung und die Veräußerung von
>   Finanzinstrumenten oder deren **Nachweis** (Anlagevermittlung)
>
> **[Makler- und Bauträgerverordnung §1](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bundesrecht/gewo_34cdv/gesamt.pdf)**
>   Gewerbetreibende, die
>   1. ... den Abschluß von Verträgen über Darlehen vermitteln oder die Gelegenheit zum Abschluß solcher Verträge
>   **nachweisen** oder
>   2. den Abschluß von Verträgen über die Nutzung der von ihnen ... verwalteten Grundstücke ... vermitteln oder die Gelegenheit zum
>   Abschluß solcher Verträge **nachweisen**,
>   unterliegen hinsichtlich dieser Tätigkeit nicht den Vorschriften dieser Verordnung.
>
> **[Verbraucherkreditgesetz §1](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bundesrecht/verbrkrg/gesamt.pdf)**
>   (1) Dieses Gesetz gilt für Kreditverträge und Kreditvermittlungsverträge zwischen
>   einem Unternehmer, der einen Kredit gewährt (Kreditgeber) oder vermittelt oder
>   **nachweist** (Kreditvermittler), und einem Verbraucher.
>
> **[Wohnungsvermittlungsgesetz §1](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/wovermrg/__1.html)** (bereits [von Takkat angeführt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/second-meaning-of-nachweisen-in-bureaucratese-german/15657#15657))
>   (1) Wohnungsvermittler im Sinne dieses Gesetzes ist, wer den Abschluß von Mietverträgen über Wohnräume vermittelt oder die Gelegenheit zum Abschluß von Mietverträgen über Wohnräume **nachweist**.

Und schließlich der vermutlich für die Passage, die Anlaß zur Frage gab, relevante 
Paragraph

> **[BGB §652](http://dejure.org/gesetze/BGB/652.html)**
>   (1) Wer für den **Nachweis** der Gelegenheit zum Abschluss eines Vertrags oder für die Vermittlung eines Vertrags einen Mäklerlohn verspricht, ist zur Entrichtung des Lohnes nur verpflichtet, wenn der Vertrag infolge des **Nachweises** oder infolge der Vermittlung des Mäklers zustande kommt.

Siehe dazu auch ["Nachweis oder Vermittlung: Wann der Makler Geld bekommt"](http://www.welt.de/welt_print/wirtschaft/article4574029/Nachweis-oder-Vermittlung-Wann-der-Makler-Geld-bekommt.html) aus der Welt am Sonntag.

---

<sup>¹ Ich benutze hier absichtlich nicht das Wort "Vermittlung", da es in den Beispielen z.T. nochmal extra in der Bedeutung von "zustande bringen, herbeiführen" benutzt wird.</sup>

Comment: Sehr schöne Antwort. Interessant, wie noch nicht einmal ein Artikel, der Laien aufklären soll, die ungewöhnliche Verwendung des Wortes aufgreift, die sicher nicht jedem Muttersprachler bekannt ist.

Answer (score 3):

Ein Begriff, in dem *nachweisen* in ähnlicher Bedeutung wie in deinem Beispiel verwendet wird, ist *Zimmernachweis,* [laut DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=Zimmernachweis) eine »Stelle, die Zimmer zum Übernachten vermittelt«.
Das passt meiner Meinung nach auch gut zur Definition im Duden. Im Zimmernachweis werden Ortsunkundige mit Informationen versorgt, welche Zimmer zu welchen Konditionen verfügbar sind, damit ein Vertrag zustandekommen kann.

Answer (score 2):

Diese Formulierung ist offenbar einem Vertrag mit einem Immobilienmakler entnommen, der eine Mietsache vermittelt hat und nun seine Vermittlungsgebühr beansprucht.

Sie bezieht sich auf folgende Passage im dies regelnden [Wohnungsvermittlungsgesetz §2](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/wovermrg/__2.html):

> *(1) Ein Anspruch auf Entgelt für die Vermittlung oder den Nachweis der Gelegenheit zum Abschluß von Mietverträgen über Wohnräume steht dem Wohnungsvermittler nur zu, wenn infolge seiner Vermittlung oder infolge seines Nachweises ein Mietvertrag zustande kommt.*

Unter dem *"Nachweis"* verstehen die Juristen hier die Zurverfügungstellung von Informationen, die es dem Mietinteressenten ermöglichen, einen Mietvertrag abzuschliessen. Der Makler **weist** seinem Kunden also **nach**, dass hier ein Wohnung zu mieten ist.